# Elastic Beanstalk appsettings.json not working

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use an Elastic Beanstalk Environment with multiple .NET Core 5.0 projects.

The Apps are running fine with my Procfile

```
api-user: dotnet ./api-user/api-user.dll --urls http://localhost:5000
api-shop: dotnet ./api-shop/shop.dll --urls http://localhost:5001
```

Unfortunately .NET seems to be unable to pick up the Configuration from my `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.<ENVIRONMENT>.json` files.

I logged all registered `ConfigurationProviders` in .NET and they are present as `JsonConfigurationProvider`

Also the files are present in the working directory. I checked that via SSH with:

```sh
cd var/app/current/api-user
cat appsettings.json
```

Configuration with `appsettings.json` works fine locally in `Development` and `Production`.
Why is this not the case for the cloud environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure it out.
The reason for the missing `appsettings.json` is the BasePath of the Application

Before running `dotnet` command i need to `cd` into the working directory:

```
api-user: cd api-user && dotnet api-user.dll --urls http://localhost:5000
api-shop: cd api-shop && dotnet shop.dll --urls http://localhost:5001
```

Comment: Lucky you were here. I may be the only other person so far who had the exact same issue. It gets lonely on SO the deeper you get into AWS for different frameworks. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you run locally, VS reads `launchSettings.json` file, where `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable is set to the right value (dev, production).

When you run in the cloud, environment variable is not present. I cannot tell you for Amazon, but when you run in Azure, you have to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in the properties of the deployed application in the Cloud (i.e. this is not part of your VS solution, but of the deployed application). I guess Amazon would have something similar and a place to set this variable.

If you run .net app from a shell (I just really don't know how beanstalk works) you should set the env variable, e.g.

`setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"`

or however your shell does it.

Comment: `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set in App configuration. I already checked this.
Also `appsettings.json` should still work