# EBS deployment with AWS CodePipelines successful, but getting 2 errors when Startup.cs runs

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

To deploy to EBS (Elastic Beanstalk) I used to run `dotnet publish -r linux-x64 --self-contained true --output build` in my terminal and then go to the build folder, select all files, compress to zip file, and upload to Elastic Beanstalk in the EBS console. The app fully worked on EBS when deployed this way.

Now I am automating it by using AWS CodePipelines.

I followed [this tutorial.](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/deploying-aspnet-core-web-api-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-using-aws-codepipeline/)

I added this "buildspec.yml" to the root of my project:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin --channel STS
    # runtime-versions: 
    #   dotnet: 7.0
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - dotnet restore Vepo.Web/Vepo.Web.csproj
      - dotnet restore Vepo.Services/Vepo.Services.csproj
      - dotnet restore Vepo.Infrastructure/Vepo.Infrastructure.csproj
      - dotnet restore Vepo.Domain/Vepo.Domain.csproj
      - dotnet restore Vepo.DataContext/Vepo.DataContext.csproj
      - dotnet restore Vepo.Data/Vepo.Data.csproj
      - dotnet restore Vepo.Common/Vepo.Common.csproj
      - dotnet restore Vepo.Application/Vepo.Application.csproj
  build:
    commands:
      - dotnet build -r linux-x64 --self-contained true Vepo.Web/Vepo.Web.csproj
  post_build:
    commands:
      - dotnet publish -r linux-x64 --self-contained true -c Release -o ./app/ Vepo.Web/Vepo.Web.csproj
artifacts:
  files:
    - "**/*"
```

and this Procfile:

```
web: dotnet ./app/Vepo.Web.dll
```

It deploys to EBS successfully. However in the EBS logs, it shows:

> Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: Unhandled exception.
> System.Exception: Could not resolve a service of type
> 'Vepo.Infrastructure.IGroceryItmsSearchIndexService' for the parameter
> 'searchIndexService' of method 'Configure' on type 'Vepo.Web.Startup'.
> Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: --->
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter
> 'uriString') Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName) Jul 31 01:22:14
> ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> System.ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Object argument, String
> paramName) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> System.Uri..ctor(String uriString) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234
> web: at Vepo.Infrastructure.SearchService..ctor(String uri, String
> username, String password, String defaultIndex, Boolean forceInMemory,
> Boolean refreshOnUpdate) in
> /codebuild/output/src3059167450/src/Vepo.Infrastructure/Search/Search.cs:line
> 42 Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Vepo.Web.Startup.b__8_7(IServiceProvider
> serviceProvider) in
> /codebuild/output/src3059167450/src/Vepo.Web/Startup.cs:line 211 Jul
> 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) Jul 31 01:22:14
> ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) Jul 31 01:22:14
> ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
> scope) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type serviceType) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance,
> IApplicationBuilder builder) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: ---
> End of inner exception stack trace --- Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234
> web: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object
> instance, IApplicationBuilder builder) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234
> web: at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost
> host) Jul 31 01:22:14 ip-172-31-1-234 web: at
> Vepo.Web.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> /codebuild/output/src3059167450/src/Vepo.Web/Program.cs:line 12

The errors seem to indicate that my `GroceryItmsSearchIndexService` is no longer registered and my "appsettings.json" file is not working anymore because this is the code in `Startup.cs` where the errors occur:

```
    services.AddScoped<ISearchService, SearchService>(serviceProvider =>
    {
        return new SearchService(
                Configuration["openSearchEndpoint"],
                Configuration["openSearchUsername"],
                Configuration["openSearchPassword"],
                Configuration["openSearchIndexName"]);
    });

    services.AddScoped<IGroceryItmsSearchIndexService, GroceryItmsSearchIndexService>();
```

Where this:

> web: at Vepo.Infrastructure.SearchService..ctor(String uri, String
> username, String password, String defaultIndex, Boolean forceInMemory,
> Boolean refreshOnUpdate)

Is referring to the code above passing in nulls where `Configuration["openSearchXXX"]` is passed in.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Open the proj file with a text editor.  You have the same files in both the json and the proj file.  You can delete the lines that are duplicates from the proj file.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry I am confused. Can you elaborate? What json?

Answer (score 0):

[This person had a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69674118/3935156). The issue is the Procfile. The Procfile associates "appsettings.json" with the app by running the dll from the location that contains the appsettings.json.

Procfile before:

```
web: dotnet ./app/Vepo.Web.dll
```

Procfile after:

```
web: cd app && dotnet Vepo.Web.dll
```